# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Height'

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am able to convert a csv file to pandas DataFormat and able to print out the table, as seen below. However, when I try to print out the Height column I get an error. How can I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path../NavieBayes.csv')
print df #this prints out as seen below
print df.Height  #this gives me the "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Height'

      Height   Weight  Classifer
0      70.0      180     Adult
1      58.0      109     Adult
2      59.0      111     Adult
3      60.0      113     Adult
4      61.0      115     Adult
```

Comment: What does `print df.columns` show?  Maybe you have some extra whitespace in the column names.

Comment: The tutorial shows a typedf) --> pandas.core.series.Series                      However, when I use type(df) -->pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: print df.columns                                                                            Index([u'Height ', u'Weight ', u'Classifer'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have run into a similar issue before when reading from `csv`. Assuming it is the same:

```
col_name =df.columns[0]
df=df.rename(columns = {col_name:'new_name'})
```

The error in my case was caused by (I think) by a byte order marker in the csv or some other non-printing character being added to the first column label. `df.columns` returns an array of the column names. `df.columns[0]` gets the first one. Try printing it and seeing if something is odd with the results.

Answer (score 2):

PS On above answer by JAB - if there is clearly spaces in your column names use skipinitialspace=True in read_csv e.g.

df = pd.read_csv('/path../NavieBayes.csv',skipinitialspace=True)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'path_of_file\csv_file_name.csv')
```

OR

```
df = pd.read_csv('path_of_file/csv_file_name.csv')
```

Example:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'F:\Desktop\datasets\hackathon+data+set.csv')
```

Try it, it will work.